# Dynamically changing multiple check boxes ID with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dynamic-controls

Whats the best way for me to change the ID's of the check boxes, like as in using a loop, the problem I'm having is with the current control ID **CheckBox1.ID**, i cant seem to change the **1** to be used as a variable

```
CheckBox1.ID = "chckbx_1";
CheckBox2.ID = "chckbx_2";
CheckBox3.ID = "chckbx_3";
CheckBox4.ID = "chckbx_4";
CheckBox5.ID = "chckbx_5";
CheckBox6.ID = "chckbx_6";
```

Is there any way where i can implement this logic?, and please note, I'm using web forms

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use a CheckBoxList rather than individual checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < some_number; i++) 
{    
    Control myControl = FindControl("CheckBox" + i.ToString());

    if(myControl != null && myControl.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox)) 
    {
        ((CheckBox)myControl).ID = "chckbx_" + i.ToString();
        ((CheckBox)myControl).CssClass = "newClass";
    }
}
```

Comment: And if i want to add, remove CssClass on this control, what then?

Comment: Then you can just call: myControl.CssClass = "something";

Comment: Which part? Are you being able to get the controls? Or it's just the CssClass bit that isn't working?

Comment: I've complemented the answer.

Comment: im not getting all the controls